# Why does -Verbose make Copy-Item ignore ErrorActionPreference?

Tags: powershell

Adding -Verbose to a Copy-Item command seems to make the command ignore the value of $ErrorActionPreference. Is that a bug or something that I don't understand?

I think this script should stop before it displays "Why is this displayed...".

```
$ErrorActionPreference="Stop"
Get-Variable ErrorActionPreference | out-default
Get-Variable ErrorActionPreference -Scope Script | out-default
Get-Variable ErrorActionPreference -Scope Global | out-default

Copy-Item This.Is.Not.There.dat $Home -Verbose
Write-Host "Why is this displayed? The script should have stopped."

Copy-Item This.Is.Not.There.dat $Home
Write-Host "This is not displayed because the script stops."
```

Here is the output that I get:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
ErrorActionPreference          Stop



Name                           Value
----                           -----
ErrorActionPreference          Stop



Name                           Value
----                           -----
ErrorActionPreference          Continue


Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\users\John\Documents\This.Is.Not.There.dat' because it does not exist.
At C:\users\John\Documents\VerboseDoesNotStop.ps1:6 char:1
+ Copy-Item This.Is.Not.There.dat $Home -Verbose
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\John\D...s.Not.There.dat:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand

Why is this displayed? The script should have stopped.
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\users\John\Documents\This.Is.Not.There.dat' because it does not exist.
At C:\users\John\Documents\VerboseDoesNotStop.ps1:9 char:1
+ Copy-Item This.Is.Not.There.dat $Home
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\users\John\D...s.Not.There.dat:String) [Copy-Item], ItemNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Comment: Interesting, seems to be a bug. If you instead use `$VerbosePreference='Continue'
` it works, but not when using the `-Verbose` switch. I tried in PowerShell 7.1 as well and it works as expected there (stopping even when using `-Verbose`).

Comment: To be fair, it's usually better to always use `-ErrorAction Stop` rather than set the preference globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a **[known bug](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/32181772-move-item-s-verbose-causes-erroractionpreference)** in *Windows PowerShell* that has since been **fixed in *PowerShell [Core]* as of (at least) v7.0.3**, which is the LTS version as of this writing (I'm not sure in what specific version the fix was introduced).

Here's a minimal example to reproduce the problem:

```
& { 
  $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
  Get-Item \no\such\path -Verbose
  '!! Should not get here' 
}
```

With the bug present, the string `!! Should not get here` unexpectedly prints, even though execution should have been aborted due to the `Get-Item` call triggering a *non-terminating* error.

A statement-*terminating* error, by contrast, is *not* affected by the bug; e.g., if you use `Get-Item -NoSuchParam -Verbose` instead, execution is aborted as expected.

Given that *Windows PowerShell* is no longer being actively developed, this bug may never get fixed - though perhaps if enough users show interest in the [open bug report](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/32181772-move-item-s-verbose-causes-erroractionpreference), it will (note that the report only mentions `Move-Item`, but it seems that all cmdlets are affected).

---

**Workarounds**:

- Instead of `-Verbose`, use the `$VerbosePreference` variable.

```
& { 
 $ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
 $VerbosePreference = 'Continue' 
 Get-Item \no\such\path
 '!! Should not get here'
}
```

- Instead of `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`, use `-ErrorAction Stop` on every cmdlet call:

```
& { 
 Get-Item \no\such\path -Verbose -ErrorAction Stop
 '!! Should not get here'
}
```